# What cache stores the windows PATH and how do I clear it?

Tags: php

I am using PHP in an HTML5 document in Windows 10,  calling shell_exec() which I want to use to call Rscript, ultimately.  The problem I have run into is that the environmental %PATH% variable in Windows that shell_exec() is getting from some cache somewhere is yesterday's version, which doesn't include the path to Rscript, so the call fails.

I carefully set both the personal and the system environmental PATH variables in Windows using the Windows tool to include a path to Rscript, and then later to remove another link to PERL to make sure the total path was below 260 characters, then I moved the Rscript path up to the front.  No joy.

The following command pulls up a %PATH% from somewhere but I have no idea where  If I simply use CMD to go to that directory and issue the commands via that shell, they find the right path, but if I call it via shell_exec() it's the old path. I've tried rebooting and clearing the browser caches so I'm pretty sure this is a PHP cache thing, but I see many references to cahces here to figure out which one I'm facing.

So any help would be appreciated.

This code shows the OLD path, not the current one:

```
 shell_exec("echo %PATH% > outputFilexx.Rout 2> errorFilexx.Rout");
```

Comment: oh i'm using PHP 8.0.8 from the Bitnami WAMP stack:  and yes, I tried shutting off and restarting the Apache2 server as well. PHP 8.0.8 (cli) (built: Jun 29 2021 16:02:52) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.8, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.8, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Comment: Environment variables are usually cached by the process, so you’d probably want to restart PHP itself. Unless you are running PHP as yourself, that is the wrong “personal” set of environment variables, however editing the system should probably have been good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are not really *cached* but simply part of the run-time environment of a process. A new process inherits all environment variables and their values - at that time when it is started - from its parent process.
After that changing the value of an environment variable in one process does not affect other (already running) processes.

How to change an environment variable of a running process depends on the program and may not always be possible. To "reload" environment variables otherwise you need to restart the process - and possibly also their parent processes since otherwise they would inherit the "old" values from them again.

I.e. you not only should restart PHP/Apache but also the WAMP console so `%PATH%` is inherited from the system environment. To be completely sure you can just reboot the whole machine.

But environment variables may also be change via application depend configurations. So you could change the `PATH` only for

- Apache via [`SetEnv`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#setenv)
- PHP via [`putenv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php)